# Four pairs of integers are selected at random from 1 to 26. What is the probability that the sum of any pair does not exceed 26?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, integers

If only one pair is selected then the probability is simply $\frac{26\cdot12}{26\cdot25}$. But how to solve the problem with several pairs that are jointly (not independently) drawn?

Comment: Just to be clear: are all eight numbers (four pairs) drawn without replacement?

Comment: And if they're not independently drawn, don't we have to know their joint distribution? In any case, you haven't specified a distribution -- I suspect that by "at random" you intended to imply "uniformly at random"?

Comment: This entails a long and tedious solution. Because the probability of a second draw is dependent on the outcome of the first draw, one has to take into account all possible first draws............and repeat the process for the third and fourth draws. I don't see a shortcut but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: You can approximate it. There are $\frac {26*25}=650$ possible pairs (order counts) of which nearly but less than 12 to less than 26.  So prob is approximately $(\frac 12)^4 = \frac 1{16}$ somewhat less but of course this isn't exact as the pair are not being replaces. and the if the first pair is one pair that changes the possible second pairs are.  But it should be very very close to $\frac 1{16}$.

Comment: yes, all eight numbers are drawn without replacement

Comment: Picking a 26 immediately fails so if you can calculate the answer for 1 to 25 then multiply by $\frac{20}{26}$ $\big($P (not picking a 26)$\big)$ you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a computer program to slog through all the possibilities, and also a Monte Carlo program. The results agree and are:
1 pair:  12/25 = 0.48 (easily done by hand);
2 pairs: 374/1725 ~ 0.216812;
3 pairs: 44/483 ~ 0.091097;
4 pairs: 13408/382375 ~ 0.035065 (much less than 1/16).
This may be useful as a check if anyone finds a better method.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\tfrac1{4!}\tbinom{26}2\tbinom{24}2\tbinom{22}2\tbinom{20}2=164038875$ ways to choose a set of four disjoint pairs of integers from the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots 26\}$.

Suppose we have chosen four pairs, such that for each pair the sum is no greater than $26$. Let $S$ be the union of all the pairs, containing eight elements. Then $S$ cannot contain more than four integers greater than $13$, and any such integer must be paired with an integer smaller than $13$.

Consider the case in which the union $S$ contains four elements $w,x,y,z$ such that $13<w<x<y<z<27$. It must also contain four elements $a,b,c,d$ such that $0<a<b<c<d<14$. What can those elements be?

Say we choose $z$ first. Then it must be paired with a number below or equal to $26-z$. After that we choose $y$ such that $13<y<z$. It must be paired with a number below or equal to $26-y$, but not equal to the number paired with $z$. After that we choose $x$, and so on.

$$\begin{matrix}.]&.&.&.&.&.]&.&.&.&.&[.\\\hline 0&26-z&26-y&26-x&26-w&13&w&x&y&z&26\end{matrix}$$

Thus for any specific $(w,x,y,z)$ there are $(26-z)(26-y-1)(26-x-2)(26-w-3)$ choices for $(w',x',y',z')$, where $w$ is paired with $w'$, etc.

$$\begin{align*}&\sum_{13<w<x<y<z<27} (26-z)(26-y-1)(26-x-2)(26-w-3)
\\=&\sum_{0<a<b<c<d<13} a(b-1)(c-2)(d-3)
\\=&\sum_{0<a\le b\le c\le d<10} abcd
\\=&\lbrace\textstyle{13\atop 9}\rbrace
\end{align*}$$

where $\lbrace{n\atop k}\rbrace$ denotes the Stirling number of the second kind.

Now consider the case in which the union $S$ contains exactly three elements $x,y,z$ such that $13<x<y<z<27$. We can pair off these elements as shown above; finally, both elements of the last pair are no greater than $13$, and can be selected from those left over in $\tbinom{13-3}2=45$ ways. Thus we count

$$\begin{align*}&\tbinom{10}{2}\sum_{0<a\le b\le c<11} abc
\\=&\tbinom{10}{2}\lbrace\textstyle{13\atop 10}\rbrace\end{align*}$$

The remaining cases, in which there are two elements greater than $13$, or one, or none, can be treated in the same way. Summing all the cases together, we get

$$\lbrace\textstyle{13\atop 9}\rbrace
+\tbinom{10}{2}\lbrace\textstyle{13\atop 10}\rbrace
+\tfrac{1}{2!}\tbinom{11}{2}\tbinom{9}{2}\lbrace\textstyle{13\atop 11}\rbrace
+\tfrac{1}{3!}\tbinom{12}{2}\tbinom{10}{2}\tbinom82\lbrace\textstyle{13\atop 12}\rbrace
+\tfrac{1}{4!}\tbinom{13}{2}\tbinom{11}{2}\tbinom92\tbinom72$$

which equals $5752032$. On dividing this number by $164038875$, we obtain the probability $0.035065054$ or about $3.5\%$.